# Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given

Tags: php, laravel, package

I try to sign up by Facebook, using Laravel 7 and package (Socialite), when press on the URL:

```
<div class="form-group row mb-0">
     <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
          <a href="{{url('redirect/facebook')}}">login with your facebook account</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

The redirect page runs the app, i created in facebook developers as the img:

[image]

when press (continue as Mahmoud) and put my email and pass this error shows:

TypeError
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in C:\wamp64\www\Starter\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php on line 65

and URL upove chrom box the following:

http://localhost:8000/callback/facebook?code=AQDlnu6qDKxTV6nG_vN4DYMKSyVP-zEKTL_uJDKbENBTc-pBwtIxpLRkcUS_zebL3nbPo8RjKKC3D_UbZkHM8dz5iZU8c4-PPPdyS_teoLZZ77kVf1pLGCx0ggTwx0EJys8nK3aPE8BugkbgcXTFUt7qcDxQcX1ptlmG9_0qSbuifaEg678bl71Gbm3qU5Jx-*ZsonmuadY3kHTbq8vG-3s2jqV4KkxDSCw-m-4LrIe46v73EXFzG1wFNMbkWB4MJay5ZewPjI2ah3p8o5FCgGLp1Rs4clsKW5B2fQyoWc6MM-Ut2jESoQ7YMOjZpuX5kA1aWP3To1TncAjKpWsAevIa&state=n0XP5Kf68IZlOUqm1pwUYryb9md9nHCdSnatvbpO#*=_

my Routes:

```
Route::get('/redirect/{service}','SocialiteController@redirect');
Route::get('/callback/{service}','SocialiteController@callback');
```

Controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class SocialiteController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect($service){
        return Socialite::driver($service)->redirect();

    }
    public function callback($service){

         $user = Socialite::with($service) -> user();
         return $user;

    }

}
```

.env:

```
FB_CLIENT_ID = FB_ID
FB_CLIENT_SECRET = FB_secret
FB_REDIRECT = 'http://localhost:8000/callback/facebook'
```

config/services.php:

```
 'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env ('FB_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env ('FB_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env ('FB_REDIRECT')
],
```

in config/app.php i added:

```
Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
```

and

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

please could you help me i try lot of solves but no way.

Comment: My guess is, that your `callback` function in your Controller should return a Response instead of the `$user` object. Do you maybe have a full stack trace, i.e. where the invalid Response was created?

Comment: By the way your post contained your facebook client id + secret. Those are potentially sensitive information and should be changed if possible

Comment: thank you very much every one, it's right i  should return a Response instead of the $user object in controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i should return a Response instead of the $user object in controller

change

```
public function callback($service){

     $user = Socialite::with($service) -> user();
     return $user;

}
```

to

```
        public function callback($service){
           $user = Socialite::with($service)->stateless()->user();
           return response()->json($user);
    
        }
```

Comment: you save my day! Beer for you! Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function callback($service){
    $user = Socialite::with($service) -> user();
    return (array)$user;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual solution? To cast $user to an array?